# Multiple events activated in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I just learned that Twisted uses a single thread to handle events. Hence you have to design non-blocking event handlers and ideally they will have to finish before another event is triggered. Requiring that blocking routines be implemented using deferred objects.

Now, let's say you are handling an event, and another event is activated.

A reasonable reaction to this scenario would be to queue the new event and wait until the running handler finishes.

Is this what's happening inside the Twisted engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the operating system delivers events to Twisted.  In most APIs, you have to actively pull events off a queue of some kind, you don't get alerted immediately when they happen.  In situations where notifications do happen immediately (from a signal, or from another thread) Twisted enqueues them on the main thread instead.

So, from your perspective as a programmer using Twisted, the answer to your question is simply "yes", but Stack Overflow makes me put more words in for it to be considered a valid answer :).